# Why infinity equals to infinity in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why Infinity equals to Infinity in Javascript? Please consider following examples:

```
Math.pow(10,1000)
```

The above will evaluate to Infinity.

```
Math.pow(11,1000)
```

The above will evaluate to infinity as well.

However in actual Math.pow(11,1000) is greater than Math.pow(10,1100). Please help me to understand the reason behind them being equal.

Comment: infinity is not a rational number, you can't have twice infinity. It's infinite.

Comment: If Math.Pow(10,1000) equals infinity why would you think anything LARGER would resolve to anything else....
Infinity mesns never ending.

Comment: Or in the case of Javascript, it means 'too large to represent'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 2):

They're equal because that's how Javascript represents numbers that are too large for it to represent effectively.

> The MAX_VALUE property has a value of approximately 1.79E+308. Values larger than MAX_VALUE are represented as "Infinity".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity